# Elastic Search on AWS Fargate

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-fargate

Facing a problem while deploying elasticsearch on AWS Fargate

Following steps were done :

customized my docker image and pushed to AWS ECR.
task definition for my elasticsearch service

elastic search service fails on bootstrap following is the exception
**[3]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]**

its known es issue for es 5.0 onwards. Solution provided by es is as follows
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode

is it possible to apply this command on AWS Fargate as we donot have access to host ?

**Update** : Elastic Search has provided an option to avoid mmaps check on bootup but **not yet released** as of now

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/32421

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elk-on-aws-fargate/153967/4

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you cannot do that.

Let me explain:

Docker actually wraps a **process** and runs it using the kernel installed on the **host** machine.

Changing "vm.max_map_count" is actually **configuring the Linux kernel of the host machine**.

When the host machine is under your control, such as when you use EC2, you can configure the kernel of the host machine by applying "user data" on your *Launch Configuration*. (See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html)

But where host machine is not under your control, as in the case of Fargate, you cannot change the host and the kernel settings it runs. The whole idea of Fargate is to run **stateless** Docker images, images that don't make any assumptions on the host they run inside.

However, in Elasticsearch, the application itself depends on specific host configuration (the "vm.max_map_count" setting) which means that it **indeed does make assumptions about its host** and therefore it cannot run on *generic* host such as Fargate (unless you disable this check, which is not a good idea for production environment).

Comment: i think elastic search has fixed this in latest version and we need not set vm.max_map_count explicitly ... https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elk-on-aws-fargate/153967/4

Comment: @MusabQamri, even if they have disabled, they disabled the **check** only! 

You still need for production use, to set this kernel setting. 

What is the context you use ES? Production or dev / test?